# VirtualAlloc problem allocating memory for bulk file reading

Tags: c, windows, winapi

Im trying to read some data from  a binary file into a buffer allocated with VirtualAlloc.
The problem is that i get a "bad Pr" problem and can't perform an fread.
Here is my code:

```
fseek(myfile,0, SEEK_END);
DWORD FileSize = ftell(myfile);
fseek(myfile,0, SEEK_SET);
BYTE *buf = (BYTE * )VirtualAlloc(NULL,FileSize,MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
fread(buf,sizeof(BYTE),1,myfile);
```

the fread - fails.
what am i doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: What error code does it fail with?

Comment: Check all return values, also check GetLastError.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass both `MEM_RESERVE` and `MEM_COMMIT`. And you need to use a `BYTE *`, not a `BYTE`

```
fseek(myfile,0, SEEK_END);    
DWORD FileSize = ftell(myfile);    
fseek(myfile,0, SEEK_SET);    
BYTE * buf = (BYTE*)VirtualAlloc(NULL,FileSize,MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
fread(buf,FileSize,1,myfile);
```